# Show or hide admin custom setting fields, based on WooCommerce product type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I made custom field backend, which i want to be showed for simple product types and hided for other types. I think little is not enought to me to achieve it. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!
Code I added is:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'show_this_for_simple_products_and_hide_for_others');
function show_this_for_simple_products_and_hide_for_others() {  
?> 
<script>
    jQuery( function($){

    $( 'body' ).on( 'woocommerce-product-type-change', function( event, select_val, select ) {

        if ( select_val === 'simple' ) {
             // modify to an actual CSS class selector
            $( '.p.form-field.final_product_sku_field' ).show();
        }

    } );

    $( 'select#product-type' ).change();

} );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

You don't need that as there is already some CSS class selector that allows that.

To show a field for "simple" product type, you need to add in between your custom setting fields *(**inside** your function)*:

```php
echo '<div class="show_if_simple hidden">';

// Your fields here (for "simple" products type only)

echo '</div >';
```

> You can use the `show_if_{$product_type}` or `hide_if_{$product_type}` **composite class selectors**, to show or hide custom settings product fields based on the product type *(where `{$product_type}` need to be replaced by the targeted product type)*.
>
> **It works for all custom product types**.
>
> The class selector `hidden` specify that the content is **hidden** for non specified product types to be shown.
>
> You can also use those other class selectors like `show_if_virtual`, `hide_if_virtual`, `show_if_downloadable` and `hide_if_downloadable`.
>
> The class selector `options_group` adds a separator horizontal line.

Here is an example (field is shown only for simple products):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'add_product_final_sku_custom_field' );
function add_product_final_sku_custom_field(){
    global $post, $product_object;

    echo '<div class="show_if_simple hidden">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'label' => __( 'Final SKU', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Enter final SKU here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'id' => 'final_sku',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'This SKU is for final use only.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You can see that [on the related core html files code source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/5.1.0/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views) that displays WooCommerce Product setting fields on admin single product pages.

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm :))
I test know and worked for custom product types (:
Is there other css tricks like this for woocommerce or some websites, where I can learn about them?
Thank you again!

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов Tell me if it works for custom product types… Always look to WooCommerce related core files, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: Yes, I will create this habit.
It's works for custom product types